# How to change image with device language? Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a background image that has some texts too. So I want to change it with the device language. But the background changes with if statement in my code. So I need to change the image itself to optimize it for another language. How can I make this happen?

Comment: The background you are referring to and the image are not the same ?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on localisation: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a UIImage with the "imageNamed" constructor, but use an NSLocalizedString for the image name:

```
UIImage* localizeImg = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"imageNameKey", nil)];
```

Then in your localized .strings files you just put the name of the image that you want tied to that language.

```
"imageNameKey" = "englishBackground.png";
```

Apply the newly created UIImage to the background and voila!  Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your help. can you tell me a bit more about localized . strings ? how to edit them and where are them :D

Comment: I assumed that since you were trying to localize images that had text in them, that you were already localizing some of the text in your app as well. The link that @Nick provided in a comment on your post will help you set up localization in your app.  Quite honestly, the implementation of localizing images demonstrated in the tutorial is the proper way of doing so.  I never knew you could localize images like that.